# AUTH (crontab command not allowed) - Bitnami LAMP Stack centos

Tags: apache, cron, lamp, bitnami

I'm trying to setup a crontab to execute at set intervals. The crontab job is setup as part of my PHP-Slim application running on Apache. For some reason, it just doesn't add the job to the crontab, so when I run the command:

```
crontab -u daemon -l
```

It says 'no crontab for daemon' (daemon is the default Apache account). I did manage to get the cronjob manually added using another account (and it executes with no further issues) so it's most likely a permissions issue. What is the best way to troubleshoot this, without resorting to things like chmod 777 (it will be a production server so I need to careful with setting permissions and documenting them)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find the answer just after posting.

I looked in the log file for cron:

```
cat /var/log/cron
```

Lots of `(daemon) AUTH (crontab command not allowed)` error messages. Some further googling lead me to look at `/etc/cron/allow` which doesn't exist, but `/etc/cron.deny` does, and the daemon account was listed there. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

By default we do not allow the user `daemon` to run crontab jobs. If you want that user to run crontab jobs, you would need to modify `/etc/cron.deny` and remove the `daemon` user from there.

Hope it helps.